# jqueryValidation Engine inline ajax validation stopping form submit

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I'm trying to validate a multipart form using the jquery validateEngine plug in.
I can validate the form correctly for all fields however I want to take it one step further and use the built in ajax validation.
I want to check whether a name is unique compared to a database. This function works correctly and I get the expected results however I am unable to submit the form and by running validation in firebug console on the form it validates as false even though all fields are correct.

If I remove the ajax validation the form validates correctly so somewhere in this script a false flag is being set but I just don't know where to look or over ride it

The validation is initialised by:

```
if ($.validationEngine) {
        form.validationEngine();
    }
```

and as I say normal validation works.

I've set up the class in my form as:

```
class="input validate[required, ajax[ajaxNameCallPhp]]"
```

The script in the validation engine relating to this method has been changed to this:

```
"ajaxNameCallPhp": {
// remote json service location
"url": "http://localhost/greenFees/includes/lib/greenFee/checkName.php",
// error
"alertText": "* This name is already taken",
    "alertTextOk": "* This name is available",
"alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                },
```

Any help appreciated with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Ok - managed to get this to work after a few hours logging the script in firebug...

Anyway. The culprit of sorts is partly do do with another script - form wizard which turns a form into a wizard, it adds a next button which on click runs the validation. For some reason the validation when called from there behaves differently to the form submit.
With the ajax validation it displays a flag if the nameis ok, if it's already used or a notice when validating.
Solution 1:
Remove the wizard script but then the form doesnt behave correctly
Solution 2: remove the notice alertTextLoad - it appears the validation is treating the presence of this flag as an error rather than info - removing it meant I can keep the wizard
Ta

Comment: Since your entire form is "inside" the wizard, don't attach the validation engine until the last page, then the form will only be validated when submitting.